# prolog check if a list is in ascending order

Tags: list, prolog

I have an list and I want to check if it is ordered. Can somebody point out my error?

Thanks

```
taxinomemene([]).
taxinomemene([element1,element2|Tail]):-
        stoixio1>stoixio12,
        taxinomemene([stoixio2|Tail]).
```

Comment: In Prolog, variables must start with a capital letter or `_`. `element1`, for example, is not a variable. it's n atom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you have a singleton list and what are stoixio1 and stoixio12? the condition should be in terms of element1 and element2

```
is_sorted([]).
is_sorted([_]).
is_sorted([X,Y|T]) :-
   X=<Y,
   is_sorted([Y|T]).
```

Comment: its my mistake.
its same with element1,element2 

Thanks for your help